# Could not open ServletContext resource in Spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, servlets, google-cloud-platform

I have created spring boot application which will connect to Google cloud pub/sub and get data from topic. For authentication I have added this property `spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=C:\\Users\\Admin\\dev\\Projects\\cloud\\credentials-file.json` in `application.properties` file.

*When I run application, I get this exception*

```
> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/C:/Users/Admin/dev/Projects/cloud/credentials-file.json]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:158) ~[spring-web-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.core.DefaultCredentialsProvider.<init>(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:94) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-core-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.core.GcpContextAutoConfiguration.googleCredentials(GcpContextAutoConfiguration.java:58) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.core.GcpContextAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$375b81d4.CGLIB$googleCredentials$1(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.core.GcpContextAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$375b81d4$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$81fbe7e5.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.core.GcpContextAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$375b81d4.googleCredentials(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar:1.1.0.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.4.RELEASE.jar:5.1.4.RELEASE]
```

I tried to evaluate excretion in debug mode, **everything is working**. For this I evaluated this line in Intellij Idea.

`is = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Admin\\dev\\Projects\\cloud\\credentials-file.json");`

in this method

```
    @Override
    public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        InputStream is = this.servletContext.getResourceAsStream(this.path);
        if (is == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("Could not open " + getDescription());
        }
        return is;
    }
```

**Solution**
I moved my credentials file to folder `resources/static/my-credentials-file.json`

[image: project structure]

And changed file path in `application.properties` file (located on `src/resources` folder).

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=file:src/main/resources/static/my-credentials-file.json
spring.cloud.gcp.project-id=my-project-id
```